# Crosstalk between AC and DC

Tags: pcb, ac, noise, coupling, crosstalk

First time asking a question but I've come across something I just can't find the answer to. Whether or not it's because a silly question I hope to find out.

So I understand that with crosstalk occurs when an 'aggressor' AC signal is driven, and capacitive and inductive coupling happens.
I know that a steady state DC signal cannot couple to another signal, however can the reverse happen? Can an AC signal couple to a DC signal?
For example a signal line next to a VDC line.

Thanks in advance for any assistance, and again, apologies if it's a silly question.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! What frequency are we talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, AC noise can couple onto a DC line. The only thing that matters about the receiver is its physical shape and position, not what signals are on it.

This *is* a basic question, by the way, but that doesn't make it a bad question. I don't think it's been answered on here before, so it's worth having just in case someone else has the same question in the future.

Comment: You're welcome, hope it helped.